# strange content in ssl certificate

Tags: apache, ubuntu, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

Ubuntu 14.04
A few days ago I updated my SSL certificate on my apache server, I did a graceful restart of apache.

This morning, when apache restarted because it was scheduled from logrotate, apache did not come back up and there was an error.

```
AH02241: Init: Unable to read server certificate from file /etc/httpd/server.crt
```

I opened the ssl certificate and noticed gibberish.

```
server.key^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@0000644^@0000000^@0000000^@00000003250^@14441050256^@011575^@ 0^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ustar  ^@root^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@root^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKYwggSiAgEAAoIBAQCy4w403UHza+bH
0HY+mAtlxXgyqHKtZWn0VFkIgmBpKQmdrYqY4ZzPImnXCwPRRmdFkggE78apLifj
Xhj/BnNTcTZkoDTybX7yMNDA+cpoZc0OrDgwBDf5Bnp+MZXdJh9MXAqejcskl0
```

How did that gibberish append to the ssl certificate?

Comment: LOL `How did that gibberish append to the ssl certificate?`

Comment: tar file maybe? Not really a programming question and probably not answerable. When a file seems to have non-ascii "gibberish" it's probably more useful to post a hex dump of it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to duplicate the issue. This was caused by a bug in the tar command used to consolidate the files into one single file The tar command on this end-of-life linux operating system did not consolidate the files correctly causing the gibberish.